# My php script does not upload my file with ftp correctly

Tags: php

In my php code below, i am trying to upload a file. I have adapted this code from one of the posts on the subject. The file i have to upload has a serial number as part of the name, which is incremented everyday. So I use the glob function to put the file name in an array and loop through the array. The script works but the file created on the server is empty. I have seen a response to my question, which is to use

```
 ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

But I do have this in the script, it does not work for me. I hope someone can assist me locate what the problem is.
I am working in ubuntu 18.04, also connecting to a unix machine.
As an extra question, how would I delete the local file after transfer.
Thanks for understanding.
The code is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

 //define some variables

  $ftp_server='server-address';

 //set up basic connection
  $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
  $ftp_user_name="myuser";
  $ftp_user_pass="mypasswd";

  $remote_path = "/";
  $local_path="./";
  chdir($local_path);

   $local_file = glob("$local_path/OBS*");
   $arrlength=count($local_file);

    $cur_dir= getcwd();
    echo $cur_dir . "\n";
   //exit;

 //login with username and password
  $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
  ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
  print_r(ftp_nlist($conn_id,"."));

 for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++){
  //upload $local_file and save to $remote_path
  if(ftp_put($conn_id, "$local_path/$local_file[$x]", $remote_path, FTP_ASCII)){
    echo "Successfully written to $remote_path)\n";
  }
   else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
  }
 }
 //close the connection
 ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Comment: do you receive any error or likewise?

Comment: what do you mean by The script works but the file created on the server is empty? is it not copying the file to the remote server?

Comment: There is no error, except the message "Successfully written to /". I say the script works because of this message as well as the fact that a file with right appears on the server, but the file has zero size, and it is indeed empty.

Comment: I meant a file with the right name

Comment: Is there really nobody who can upload a file which is not empty with this script?

Comment: Try to give a regular name (without the serial number) to one file and try to upload it, I guess the server has security policies that are cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if(ftp_put($conn_id, "$local_path/$local_file[$x]", $remote_path, FTP_BINARY)){
    echo "Successfully written to $remote_path)\n";
}
```

Comment: I already tried FTP_BINARY. It gives the same result. I tried to send three files. All three names appear on the server and all are empty.